# Add new promise rejected to promises array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to add a rejected promise to my promises array if one of my checks fails. The problem is that the function to check if all checks are valid fails. This is my code:

```
let invalidPromises      = [],
    validationPromises   = [];

if ( input.val() === "" ) {
    invalidPromises.push( Promise.reject() );
} else if ( validationAllowed( invalidPromises ) )
    .......

console.log( validationAllowed( invalidPromises ) );

function validationAllowed( invalidPromises ) {
    Promise.all( invalidPromises ).then( () => {
        return true;
    } ).catch( () => {
        return false;
    } );
}
```

The output of the console.log should be false but I'm getting only undefined. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `validationAllowed` isn't returning anything. Have it return the `Promise.all` call, and then call `.then` on it to consume the Promise and get the value it resolves to. `return Promise.all` and `validationAllowed(invalidPromises).then(console.log)`

Comment: As @CertainPerformance has said, you just need to change the line to `return Promise.all( invalidPromises ).then( () => {` and it will work as you'd expect it

Comment: But how can I use the validationAllowed() function inside an if() now when I'm returning a promise and not a boolean?

Comment: `if (await validationAllowed(invalidPromises))` is one way to do it, but the better one is to have the promise `resolve()` when valid and `reject(error)` on errors. Then you'd use a `try {} catch{}` block to deal with invalid input.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Just stop using promises if you're not planning to do anything asynchronous?